# Python Java Pipe: dev/stdin file not found exception

Tags: java, python, twitter, stdin

Trying to use the python [TweetNLP](http://www.ark.cs.cmu.edu/TweetNLP/) wrapper [CMUTagger](https://github.com/ianozsvald/ark-tweet-nlp-python), but its throwing the following error:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: \dev\stdin (The system cannot find the path specified)

at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at cmu.arktweetnlp.util.BasicFileIO.openFileToReadUTF8(BasicFileIO.java:50)
    at cmu.arktweetnlp.RunTagger.runTagger(RunTagger.java:93)
    at cmu.arktweetnlp.RunTagger.main(RunTagger.java:364)
Sep 17, 2014 10:22:45 AM cmu.arktweetnlp.util.BasicFileIO openFileToReadUTF8
SEVERE: Could not open file:/dev/stdin
```

Reinstalled the JDK instead of the JRE only. Didn't fix a thing. Not sure what to do as i cant even locate the dev folder in the java directory... halp =(

Executes java program fine if the cmd line call without python is 'sh', 'runTagger.sh', '--output-format', 'conll', [File with tweets to tag], but i need it to tag incoming stream of tweets from python via stdin =)

EDIT found the dev/stdin in CygWin and tried adding the paths 'c:...\cygwin' and 'c:...\cygwin\dev' but again nothing happened

Answer (score 1):

I was stuck on this forever as well.  I found a workaround for it.

You could use the following code:

```
import subprocess

p = subprocess.check_output('java -XX:ParallelGCThreads=2 -Xmx500m -jar ark-tweet-nlp-0.3.2.jar examples/example_tweets.txt')
```

this will give you output for running the example_tweets file through the tagger.

Comment: Thank you, you sir are the hero of the day.